# How to print translatable data in sonata admin with DoctrineBehaviors from kpnlabs

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata-admin

I'm just looking the good way to use DoctrineBehaviors by knplabs.

I have allready render a form in sonata admin bundle with the help of this bundle : https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle

Now, i want to have my translated field in the admin list.

At this time, it's work with this method:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sport") 
 */

class Sport
{
...

    public function getNom(){
        return $this->translate()->getNom();
    }
}
```

It's work but, i have to remap all the translated field in the original entity. I'm pretty sure i'm missing something, particularly with the *magic* of the proxy translations.

**UPDATE:**

```
class Sport
{

    use \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translatable;

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }   
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // Need this method for the admin list template
    public function getNom(){
         return $this->translate()->getNom();
    }

    // Work even the precedent method not here, the proxy call work fine.
    public function __toString(){
         return $this->getNom();
    }
}

class SportTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string
     * @return null
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your fast reply @nifr! The proxy Method work in a controller (i try on the __toString Method of sport, it's work fine).

But the issue apparently coming from sonata admin bundle, i check the template code, don't know why it doesn't work.

I will keep the ugly method until i finda better solution.

At this time it's the only way to print value in the admin list template.

If i find something better i will update this post.

Comment: please provide your translation entity. Is "nom" a SportTranslation property?

Comment: please review my answer and comment if anything unclear otherwise please accept :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors magic proxy translations

Given you have `MyClass` and `MyClassTranslation` following the naming convention ( translation class suffixed with *Translation* ).

Only the properties which *don't* need to be translated live in `MyClass` and all translatable properties live in `MyClassTranslation`.

Let's say the translatable property shall be `description`.

---

<kbd>MyClass.php</kbd>

**Attention**: Neither property `description` nor getters/setters for `description` in `MyClass` .... otherwise `__call()` won't be invoked properly!

```
class MyClass
{

    use \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translatable;

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }

    protected $nonTranslatableProperty;

    // ...
```

---

<kbd>MyClassTranslation.php</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class MyClassTranslation
{
    use \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translation;


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return MyClassTranslation
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }
```

---

Now calling `MyClass::getDescription()` will invoke the magic method `__call()` which will return the translation using the current locale because there is no `getDescription()` method in `MyClass` .

**Solution:**

You should remove all the translatable getters/setters/properties present in `SportTranslation` from your `Sport` class and instead add the magic `__call()` method.

Comment: and when I hydrate array, I must make leftjoin?

Answer (score 2):

> At this time it's the only way to print value in the admin list template.

If you want all translations you can simply add in your admin class of sport :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
   $listMapper
       ->addIdentifier('translations')
}
```

That way the result will depends on __toString function of SportTranslation class.

Otherwise, if you want to print the current translation, I guess you should use a custom template.
For instance I will remove the getNom method in Sport.

Then in your admin class of sport :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
   $listMapper
       ->addIdentifier('translations', null, array(
           'template' => 'YourAdminBundle:CRUD:translatable.html.twig'
       ));
}
```

In your template

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field%}
{{ object }}
{% endblock %}
```

That way it will call the __toString of your sport Class and it works without the getNom method.

Unfortunately, it does not correct my problem link to yours : [How to sort translatable data in sonata admin using knplabs doctrine behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753528/how-to-sort-translatable-data-in-sonata-admin-using-knplabs-doctrine-behavior)