# How to return a localized property of an entity in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entities

I have a "Category" entity containing

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $nameFr;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $nameEn;
```

Now, I'm trying to display the localized name in the view, I can display one or the other using:

```
{{ categories.nameFr }} and {{ categories.nameEn }}
```

So I made a method called `getName()` so I can use `{{ categories.name }}`

I only needed to access the locale so I added a `protected $locale` property to the entity with the setter and getter and I set the locale before calling the view (I use @Template for the return by the way):

```
$locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale();
$categories->setLocale($locale);

return array(
    'categories' => $categories
);
```

This was working, but now I implemented a pagination bundle [KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) which requires to send a query instead of the entity:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$categoriesQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('category')
    ->from('OylexCategoryBundle:Category', 'category')
;

$locale = $this->getRequest()->getLocale();

$categoriesQuery->setLocale($locale);

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$categoriesPagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $categoriesQuery,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
    30
);

return array(
    'categoriesPagination' => $categoriesPagination
);
```

This fails with the error message: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::setLocale()`.

If I try the method `setLocale()` on `$categoriesPagination` instead, it fails with the error message: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination::setLocale()`

Is there a way to pass the locale to the entity? or Is there even a better way to handle this situation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do something like `propertyEn` and `propertyFr` in general.

Just store your translations together with a locale property which makes fetching them from database in a query as easy as:

```
// example findByLocale($locale) method

->select('entity.property')
->from('AcmeMyBundle:Entity', 'entity')   
// or inside a repository $this->createQueryBuilder('entity')

->where('entity.locale = :locale')
->setParameter('locale', $locale)
```

But this has all been done before ...

You should either use [Gemo\DoctrineExtensions\Translatable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md), which can easily be integrated with symfony2 using [Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)

... or my tip if using PHP 5.4+ with traits available [KnpLabs\DoctrineBehaviors\Translatable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable).

In order to integrate these nicely with your forms use [a2lix\TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle).

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410873/1832745) for a quick insight on using DoctrineBehaviors\Translatable and the current locale proxy which i found to be a really comfortable solution.

Just create class `Entity` and `EntityTranslation`, include the proxy lines ... call `$entity->getProperty()`

-> current locale applied automatically. as easy as it can be :-)

Comment: Thanks, I chose the traits method and it's working, but now I am trying to use a translated field as the property of a form entity field type: `'property' => 'name'` I get the error: "Neither property "name" nor method "getName()" nor method "isName()" exists in class", I tried with the query_builder option, but it says that the entity has no field or association named locale, I supose I have to join the EntityTranslation, I'll find out how to do that, is this the way or is there a better one?

Comment: Update: I tried a few things with the query_builder option and no matter what I do, "name" is never a valid value for the property option, but I can call getName();exit; in the query_builder closure and it works, it just never leaves the closure