# Knp\DoctrineBehaviors + a2lix_translations + Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, a2lix-translation

I set up my entities same as https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable . Also configs same as http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/ . Also I add __call method and try to implement [How to print translatable data in sonata admin with DoctrineBehaviors from kpnlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409580/how-to-print-translatable-data-in-sonata-admin-with-doctrinebehaviors-from-kpnla). First I get error that $name doesn't exist at Category.php. So I add it, now I have error:
 `Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "addName()"/"removeName()", "setName()", "name()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class`.
Question is how they remove setters/getters from main Entity, for me it's caused errors. Maybe someone have proper magic for all of this?

Category.php

```
class MyClass
{

    use \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translatable;

    private $name; //added after error

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->translate()->getName(); //added after error
    }

    #public function getName() {
     #   return ($this->getTranslations()); // also trying like this
    #}

    // ...
```

CategoryTranslation.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * CategoryTranslation
 */
class CategoryTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return CategoryTranslation
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

In sonata category admin:

```
$formMapper->add('name', 'a2lix_translations');
```

When I added my category(access message) I see in database "name" looks like

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000006cb11474000000002980d54f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove setters and getters from main class then `doctrine:schema:update`.
Also in sonata category admin:

```
$formMapper->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations');
```